# Conditional ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have a ui-view defined in my root template `<div ui-view=""></div>`. Is that possible to automatically hide that view if it's content is empty?

I was searching for similar thread for some time but all the people suggests is checking current route or passing vars to rootScope which i don't like. I'm looking for the simplest solution possible - checking if desired view has any content defined and if not - hide it's div (or any other html tag)

Comment: Shouldnt all yout views have content? Thats why its a view. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, actually no, they shouldnt. I have a sidebar view which is not always filled and i don't want it's container to be visible if it's empty. I can also ask - can i smehow access ui-view variable in my template? It would make me able to use ng-class for instance and deal with it using css

Comment: Well. Then I can only refer to the tips you already got. To hide the div with ng-show there has to be a variable set in some scope

Comment: Could you hide all the views that end up in that ui-view by default, and then unhide them in their controllers if they have content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to show or share - my way how to solve that. I would say it is a similar story, if I read the question carefully enough. Otherwise, take it as a hint...

Scenario: we need a place, where we can show something, if needed. And hide that if ... not needed. Let's call it **toolbar** and let's assume it is defined as a `View` on the root state, and is intended to be managed by any Child state/controller....

```
$stateProvider
 .state('myModule', {
    url: "/mm",           // sub root 'mm' like MyModule
    views: {
      'body@': {          // this way we inject into index.html
          templateUrl: ..  // the MyModule root template
          controller: 'RootCtrl',   // the root controller
       },
       'toolbarView@myModule' : { // the view is part of MyModule template
          templateUrl: ..
          controller: ..
       },
       ... // standard defintions of the root state
...
```

The essence here is that the *View* should be rendered by default. The visibility will be managed by that View:

- it should not check: is there any content inside of me...
- but it should check: Is my **Model** setting **IsVisible** set to `true`?

In fact it would be very simple. In our root controller `RootCtrl` we can/must declare a `Model` for our *`toolbar` View*:

```
// inside of the 'RootCtrl'
$scope.ToolbarModel = {
    IsVisible : false,
    ViewUrl : null,
};
$scope.ToolbarModel.close = function(){
    this.ViewUrl : null;
    this.IsVisible = false;
}
```

And this could be our *`Toolbar` View*:

```
// toolbar class can position this view from the global perspective
<div class="toolbar" 
     ng-show="ToolbarModel.IsVisible" >
     // the view is managing its visiblity by Model values 

   <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
           ng-click="ToolbarModel.close()" 
           // anyone can anywhere hide us

   </button>

   // holder class representing some inner scrolling area...
   <div class="holder"
     ng-include="ToolbarModel.ViewUrl" >
     // this way we inject the passed 'ViewUrl'

   </div>
</div>
```

That's it. The *ng included* view can contain Directives with Controllers requiring `$state`, `$stateParams`... and do a lot.

The good I see here:

- The view is defined on the root View, so we can position it from a Global perspective
- No hacking. Pure angular way

  - View is rendered always *(in fact once, while beeing part of the Root state)* and hides immediately in case `IsVisible` === `false`.
  - Any Child in any depth can use it, including the call to the `ToolbarModel.close()`
  - One click will `close()` ... not disturbing if not needed
- we are not creating any extensions here to existing `angular` an `ui-router` features, just using what is available

Finally to answer a question:

> Is that possible to automatically hide that view if it's content is empty?

Yes, we can anywhere manage the `$scope.ToolbarModel.IsVisible`.

*(NOTE: if needed here is why that model is available in every child [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/))*

Comment: Kohler, thank you for your answer. It's helpful but...
Is it possible to add some condition in `toolbarView@myModule` to decide if to add it to the root view or not? The issue which I have is that for particular situation I don't want to load it to the DOM.

Comment: @Kosmonaft I tried to show you some way here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33264254/1679310

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old question but there is another way to do this with CSS.

You can use the :empty selector to check for content and hide the ui-view div that way.