# ui router nested views condtions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

is it possible to create a nested views in ui router with conditions?
The conditions is assigned to the user roles.

For example I have two types of users: **admin** and **user**.
If user is opening the setting page then ui router is adding only this view which is assign to his role.

Here is example of my config code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);        
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){    
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .state('settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            data: {
                roles: ['admin', 'moderator', 'user']
            },
            views:{
                '':{
                    templateUrl:'/settings.html',
                },
                'piView@settings':{
                    data: {
                        roles: ['user']
                    },
                    templateUrl:'/personalInformation.html'
                },
                'permissionsView@settings':{//load this view if user is administrator
                                            //I need some condition for this
                    data: {
                        roles: ['admin']
                    },
                    templateUrl: '/permissionsView.html'
                }
            },
            controller: 'settingsController'
        });         
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function($injector) {
      var $state = $injector.get("$state");
      $state.go('/home');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view will be injected for each user (admin or anonymous). But we can manage which view. The best vay would be to use **`templateProvider`**.

Based on this Q & A:

#### [Confusing $locationChangeSuccess and $stateChangeStart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25872219/1679310)

I used the plunker from above source [and adjusted it a bit](http://plnkr.co/edit/RHQXJZZP3eZP18geSfdi?p=preview)

So, let's have these two targets *(inside of index.html)*

```
<div ui-view="onlyForAdmin"></div>    
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

And a state public, which for Admin will reveal even content of the onlyForAdmin, with settings like this:

```
.state('public', {
      url: "/public",
      data: { isPublic: true },
      views: {
        '@' : {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
          data: { isPublic: true },
        },
        'onlyForAdmin@' : {
          templateProvider: ['$templateRequest','userService',
            function($templateRequest,userService)
            {
              if(userService.isAdmin())
              {
                return $templateRequest("justForAdmin.html");
              }
              return ""; // other than admin will see nothing
            }
          ]
        } 
      } 
})
```

the content of the *justForAdmin.html* (e.g. `<h2>just for admin</h2>`) will be injected only of some authorization service will find user as admin...

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RHQXJZZP3eZP18geSfdi?p=preview)

Comment: Kohler. Thank you! Unfortunately it doesn't work for my project. I have to use Angular up to version 1.3. `$templateRequest` is a feature for v1.3 + . I have to use this version of Angular because the app should work on IE8. In fact I can use `templateUrl: function(){ if(){ retrun "templateURL"}}`

Comment: Right, good adjustment! Really ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir ;)

Comment: Thank you very much again! Thanks of you I learned something new about AngularJS :) Do you thing that my adjustment is acceptable?

Comment: My solution is not perfect. I cannot inject any services or factory to my `app.config` . Any idea how to solve my problem? Is it possible to prevent loading of template?

Comment: I guess that you can still use my approach with templateProvider. but just instead of templateRequest.. try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25290194/1679310